# Difference between print, put and say?

Tags: raku

In Perl 6, what is the difference between `print`, `put` and `say`?

I can see how `print 5` is different, but `put 5` and `say 5` look the same.

Comment: And when did `put` got introduced ? (which version of perl/raku ?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`put $a` is like `print $a.Str ~ “\n”`
`say $a` is like `print $a.gist ~ “\n”`

`put` is more computer readable.
`say` is more human readable.

```
put 1 .. 8 # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
say 1 .. 8 # 1..8
```

Learn more about [`.gist` here](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/gist).

———
More accurately, `put` and `say` append the value of the `nl-out` attribute of the output filehandle, which by default is `\n`. You can override it, though. Thanks Brad Gilbert for pointing that out.

Comment: So `.Str` is comparable to Python's `repr()` and `.gist` is comparable to Python's `str()`?

Comment: @Stefanus Yes, ironically so.

Comment: You might be interested in this page on [Perl 6 for Python users](https://docs.perl6.org/language/py-nutshell).

Comment: Actually it isn't `"\n"`, it's `$*OUT.nl-out` which defaults to `"\n"`

Comment: @BradGilbert Thanks. Good to know it’s overridable.

Answer (score 12):

Handy Perl 6 FAQ: [How and why do say, put and print differ?](https://docs.perl6.org/language/faq#How_and_why_do_say,_put_and_print_differ?)

> The most obvious difference is that `say` and `put` append a newline at the end of the output, and `print` does not.
>
> But there's another difference: `print` and `put` converts its arguments to a string by calling the `Str` method on each item passed to, `say` uses the `gist` method instead. The `gist` method, which you can also create for your own classes, is intended to create a Str for human interpretation. So it is free to leave out information about the object deemed unimportant to understand the essence of the object.
>
> ...
>
> So, say is optimized for casual human interpretation, dd is optimized for casual debugging output and print and put are more generally suitable for producing output.
>
> ...

Comment: Notes: 1) While printing a type object warns, `say`ing it, or printing its gist, does not. 2) `.perl`, which is used by `dd`, is also of interest; see the FAQ. 3) `note` is like `say`, except it prints on STDERR. (@mr_ron, please consider pasting the whole FAQ answer -- it all seems useful -- or giving me a thumbs up to do so and I'll make sure it's nicely formatted. Also, consider adding a note about `note`. Then I'll delete this comment.)